# Memory leak with closed connections

Tags: r, memory-leaks, connection, stdin

I have an R application interacting with a Java daemon via `stdin` and `stdout` in an infinite loop, which seems to have some memory leaks. Simplified R app:

```
while (TRUE) {
    con <- file('stdin', open = 'r', blocking = TRUE)
    line <- scan(con, what = character(0), nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE)
    close(con)
}
```

This loop ends up using more and more RAM, and even if I manually `gc()` after the `close(con)` call, the memory footprint seems to be OK for a while, but eventually grows forever.

A basic script to confirm this:

```
Rscript --vanilla -e "while(TRUE)cat(runif(1),'\n')" | Rscript --vanilla -e "cat(Sys.getpid(), '\n');while (TRUE) {con <- file('stdin', open = 'r', blocking = TRUE);line <- scan(con, what = character(0), nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE);close(con);gc()}"
```

This will start two R processes: one writing to `stdout` and the other reading from `stdin` connected with a pipe (and the second printing the `pid` so that you can monitor the related memory usage):

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but would love to stop this memory leak so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone interested in the discussion, the question received more traction on [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-November/thread.html#73360)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed (about reading about this on `R-devel`);
notably, the memory leak has now been plugged in the development version of R, thanks to a patch by Gabor Csardi.

Comment: Thank you very much, @martin-mächler!

Comment: I think this suggests that R 3.3.3+ should be patched.

Comment: The patch made it into the next (from Nov.2016) R release which has been 3.4.0.  3.4.2 is current (since 2 days ago!).   We don't backport patches: To do this really safely can be a lot of work which we don't have the resources (= human time) for.  (( and we'd like "everyone" to upgrade to the latest releases if possible :-))